# How to transform/animate with Chakra-UI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chakra-ui

Started using chakra-ui, and really loving it so far, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do a simple animation.

I have an image that i want to increase it's size onClick.

I've briefly looked at `framer-motion` but it seems a bit overkill for what i need.

I tried it anyways and kept getting an error when trying to define `motionBox` with typescript:

```
import { Flex, Container, HStack, Box, BoxProps } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const MotionBox = motion < BoxProps > Box;
```

errors:

`Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'ChakraComponent<"div", {}>'.ts(2365)`

`'BoxProps' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

Is there a simple way to animate with chakra? or should i just try to figure out my errors with framer?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at https://blog.logrocket.com/advanced-techniques-chakra-ui/#animations

All credits go to the blog post author [Nefe James](https://blog.logrocket.com/author/nefejames/) and where else it is due.

Here's the transcript:

> ## Animations
>
> You can define animations using Chakra UI’s keyframes helper.
> keyframes takes in a CSS keyframe definition and returns an object you
> can use in styles:
>
> ```js
> import { Box, Button, Center, VStack, keyframes } from "@chakra-ui/react"; 
> import { LightBulb } from "svgs";
>
> const spin = keyframes`  
>   from {transform: rotate(0deg);}   
>   to {transform: rotate(360deg)} 
> `;
>
> export default function Transition() {   
>   const spinAnimation = `${spin} infinite 2s linear`;   
>   return (
>     <Center>
>       <VStack spacing={20}>
>         <Box animation={spinAnimation}>
>           <LightBulb />
>         </Box>
>       </VStack>
>     </Center>   
>  ); 
> }
> ```
>
> Above, we set up a spin animation with the keyframes helper. We can
> add animations to Chakra UI elements through the animation prop.
>
> Next, we pass spinAnimation to the Box component in order to add
> animations to our applications using Chakra UI.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution using state:
Whilst it's not technically animated, it does what i need.

(I also got framer working, creating a custom motion component, but using JS not TS)

```
  const [size, setSize] = useState("20vh");

  const toggleSize = () => {
    if (size === "20vh") {
      setSize("50vh");
    } else {
      setSize("20vh");
    }
  };
```

```
 <Image
                p="5px"
                alt={product.id}
                src={product.img[1]}
                w={size}
                maxH="50vh"
                m="auto"
                borderRadius="10px"
                onClick={() => toggleSize()}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

transition="all .25s ease"
_hover={{
transform: 'scale(1.33)',
filter: "brightness(120%)",
}}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please fix your answer by using proper formatting and explaining your code. Please also provide documentation by a trusted source like Mozilla Web Docs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).